# Sentiment Analysis with OpenNLP

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, opennlp

I found this description of implementing a Sentiment Analysis task with OpenNLP. In my case I am using the newest OPenNLP-version, i.e., version 1.8.0. In the following example, they use a Maximum Entropy Model. I am using the same input.txt (tweets.txt)

http://technobium.com/sentiment-analysis-using-opennlp-document-categorizer/

```
public class StartSentiment {

public static DoccatModel model = null;
public static String[] analyzedTexts = {"I hate Mondays!"/*, "Electricity outage, this is a nightmare"/*, "I love it"*/};

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


 //     begin of sentiment analysis
    trainModel();
    for(int i=0; i<analyzedTexts.length;i++){
        classifyNewText(analyzedTexts[i]);
    }

}

  private static String readFile(String pathname) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(pathname);
        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int)file.length());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
            }
            return fileContents.toString();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

  public static void trainModel() {
      MarkableFileInputStreamFactory  dataIn = null;
     try {
        dataIn = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(
                new File("bin/text.txt"));

        ObjectStream<String> lineStream = null;
        lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ObjectStream<DocumentSample> sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);

        TrainingParameters tp = new TrainingParameters();
        tp.put(TrainingParameters.CUTOFF_PARAM, "2");
        tp.put(TrainingParameters.ITERATIONS_PARAM, "30");

        DoccatFactory df = new DoccatFactory();
        model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", sampleStream, tp, df);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (dataIn != null) {
            try {
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }

  public static void classifyNewText(String text){
      DocumentCategorizerME myCategorizer = new DocumentCategorizerME(model);

          double[] outcomes = myCategorizer.categorize(new String[]{text});
          String category = myCategorizer.getBestCategory(outcomes);

          if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
              System.out.print("The text is positive");
          } else {
              System.out.print("The text is negative");
          }

  }
```

}

In my case no matter what input String I am using, I am only getting a positive estimation of the input string. Any idea what could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: 1 = positive, 0 = negative. If it's under 0.5 it's more negative than positive. Looks like it's `works as designed`

Comment: Even if I use negative example inputs from the tweets.txt, the result is a positive value.

Comment: It is always 0.5..

Comment: It was caused because I havent split the input string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908442/opennlp-categorize-content-return-always-first-category